# How do I delete from the list?

Tags: c#

I'm kind of new to programming and come to quite of a problem.
I'm sure the solution is quite simple but I just can't get my head around it. 
I just want to know how to Delete from the listbox and delete the data from the list entirely, because whenever I delete from the list box it disappears but when I add a new layer all the layers that I have deleted come back (so I'm guessing it doesn't really delete from the list?.

This is at the start of my code at the top:

```
List<Layer> layers = new List<Layer>();
```

This is my Layers Class:

```
public class Layer
    {
        private Image mLayerData = null;
        private string mLayerName = "Layer";

        public string LayerName
        {
            get { return mLayerName; }
            set { mLayerName = value; }
        }

        public Image LayerData
        {
            get { return mLayerData; }
        }

        public Layer(int width = 500, int height = 500, string layername = "Layer")
        {
            mLayerData = new Bitmap(width, height);
            mLayerName = layername;
        }
    }
```

and this is my addLayer Function:

```
 private void addNewLayer()
        {
            string layerName = "Layer";
            layerName += layers.Count;

            // Create a default layer in our stack of layers
            layers.Add(new Layer(pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height, layerName));

            // Make the picture box talk to the default layer
            pictureBox1.Image = layers[0].LayerData;
            pictureBox1.Invalidate();

            // Update the list of layers
            listLayers.Items.Clear();
            foreach(Layer l in layers)
            {
                listLayers.Items.Add(l.LayerName);
            }

            listLayers.SelectedIndex = listLayers.Items.Count - 1;
        }
```

for my deleteLayer function I have this:

```
private void deleteLayer()
{
 listlayers.Items.RemoveAt(listlayers.SelectedIndex);
}
```

Comment: You never delete/remove from `layers` in the `deleteLayer` method

Comment: Yeah, I just realized that. I’m deleting from the listbox but not actually deleting/removing layers. I’m just stumped rig now and don’t know how to do it. Any suggestions on fixing/ doing it?

Comment: It is better to add "Layer" instance to "Listbox". Then remove it by using the code like this: listLayers.Items.Remove(listLayers.SelectedIem as Layer);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better approach would be to use [BindingList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.bindinglist-1?view=netframework-4.8), which is supports Data Binding and use `DataSource` property of `Listbox` to bind the collection.

For example,

```
BindingList<Layer> layers = new BindingList<Layer>();
listBox.DataSource = layers;
listBox.DisplayMember = nameof(Layer.LayerName);
```

Also, note that instead of binding/add names of `Layer` to the `Listbox`, you should instead bind the Collection of Layer and use the `DisplayMember` property to ensure the `LayerName` is displayed in the Listbox.

Now you could Add to the listbox as the following

```
var layer = new Layer(pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height, layerName);
layers.Add(newLayer);
```

Remove

```
layers.Remove((Layer)listBox.SelectedItem);
```

The `BindingList` would refresh the Listbox by itself.